# Order day names in a line chart in power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I want to draw a line chart which has day names in X axis. But I get those names in acceding or descending order in the X axis (as:- Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday...). I wanted to get these values as Sunday, Monday, Tuesday,...etc. How can I do that in power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than one choice here but this is the one that I tried before.  You add a new column for the Day of the week then sort the column by selecting the column and going the Modeling tab and selected new column from the Sort by Column.  Here is a link to an example.  Good Luck
http://databear.com/2016/04/23/power-bi-tips-sort-by-month-name/